# Shiny: dplyr with reactive data (or an alternatives way to use the function ifelse() )

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, reactive

I'm looking for a way to use the `ifelse()` form `dplyr` in my Shiny app.

This is working well:

```
 # First Subset:
  Rohdaten_subset <- reactive({
req(input$Filter_sex)
filter( Rohdaten, Geschlecht %in% input$Filter_sex & Alter %in% input$Filter_age)
})

# Second Subset:
Rohdaten_subset2 <- reactive({
Rohdaten_subset() %>% mutate(Alternative1 := Rohdaten_subset()[[input$Preis1]] + Rohdaten_subset()[[input$produkt1]],
                             Alternative2 := Rohdaten_subset()[[input$Preis2]] + Rohdaten_subset()[[input$produkt2]],
                             Alternative3 := Rohdaten_subset()[[input$Preis3]] + Rohdaten_subset()[[input$produkt3]],
                             Alternative4 := Rohdaten_subset()[[input$Preis4]] + Rohdaten_subset()[[input$produkt4]]
                             )%>% select(Alternative1,Alternative2,Alternative3,Alternative4)

})
```

But this part doesn't work and I don’t know why:

```
Rohdaten_subset3 <- reactive({
df <-  Rohdaten_subset2()
df$Alternative1_fc <- 0
df$Alternative1_fc[(df$Alternative1 > df$Alternative2) & (df$Alternative1 > df$Alternative3) & (df$Alternative1 > df$Alternative4)]<-1
})


Rohdaten_subset4 <- reactive({
df <-  Rohdaten_subset2()
df$Alternative1_fc <-  ifelse(df$Alternative1 > df$Alternative2 
                            & df$Alternative1 > df$Alternative3 
                            & df$Alternative1 > df$Alternative4, 1, 0) 
 })
```

I'm very happy for any kind of help!

Regards,
 Julian

**Edit 1:**
I want to build a new variable (0/1 coded) if "Alternative1" is the highest value of "Alternative1", "Alternative2", "Alternative3" and "Alternative4".
If "Alternative1" got the highest value, I want to write a 1 in my new variable `Alternative1_fc` - if not I want to write a 0 in the same variable.
It should look like this:

Comment: What exactly isn't working? e.g. what are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Hello gkubed, thanks for your answer. Please have a look at my question, I edited it.

Comment: Your `Rohdaten_subset3/4 ` reactive objects don't actually return the update data.frame. Blocks return the last thing evaluated. Just add a plain `df` to the last line of the block to return the updated data.frame. The dplyr `filter/mutate` functions do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick -  that works!!! Would you like to post your comment as answer?